# QGIS Print Layout Lagging when using SVG's

Tags: qgis, print-composer, svg

I am using QGIS version 3.22.4-Białowieża and when I use various SVGs in the print layout to create a diagram (image below) they lag/are jerky when I move an SVG object around.  I have the NVIDIA control panel usage mode set to "Dedicate to graphics tasks".  The rendering options are below (render layers in parallel using many CPU cores, enable feature simplification, etc.).  The IT guy has set my virus checker (Sophos) to dismiss the real-time scanning of some key QGIS folders (i.e. C:\OSGeo4W, `C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/svg/`).

In the QGIS environment, there are about 60 drone photos placed at certain locations using the ImportPhotos plugin.  I use these images as the background for placing the SVG's atop.

Question: Is there a way I can improve performance or do it another way?

My computer:

- 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-11700 @ 2.50GHz,
- 32.0 GB RAM,
- SSD,
- NVIDIA RTX A4000

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I abandoned the print layout route.  It was a task better suited for GIMP.